# How to call Context and Intent objects inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-context

I want to open a new Activity within `RecyclerView`, but I can't create an `Intent` object in there.

```
val intent1 = Intent(this,Main2Activity::class.java)   
startActivity(intent1)
```

Android Studio warns about Intent not being a `Context`. How can I still open a new Activity inside the `RecyclerView`

[image]

I tried also the code below,it gives "startActivity(intent)" line gives error, "type mismatch, required Context, found Intent".

Plus, also "this@MainActivity" gives "unresolved reference@MainActivity" error.

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Main_Menu_Holder, position: Int) {
        var currentview = alldata.get(position)

    }
```

Comment: If you're doing this in a OnClickListener or another class, you can't use `this`.

Comment: How can I do that? I tried different things but still doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `this` which is your `RecyclerView`'s `onBindViewHolder`. You have to call the `Context` using `View`:

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Main_Menu_Holder, position: Int, v:View) {
        val intent = Intent(v.context, Main2activity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent) 
}
```

Comment: I update the code regarding to yours, but "startActivity(intent)" line gives error, "type mismatch, required Context, found Intent".  Plus, also "this@MainActivity" gives "unresolved reference@MainActivity" error. Couldn't get it why.

Comment: @sleepy did you put this code in your mainactivity? Also is this inside your recyclerview? Please update your code above since it is really hard to know when I don't have your code. You can format your code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K

Comment: No, I want to do that in Recyclerview's "onBindViewHolder" function.

Comment: @sleepy Why in the `onBindViewHolder`? You could just do it in mainactivity. It is a bad idea to place it in `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Actually I have 2 lists(menu) and I'm using recyclerview. First menu shows, lets says car brands. When I click a car brand(itemview), it should show another layout with full screen, car models, but not in recyclerview. So that's why I'm trying to inflate within Recyclerview. Maybe it's not right method.

Comment: @sleepy I get it now. I saw your other post. Try the updated code

Comment: When I add "v:View" to function parameters, it gives an "onBinViewHolder overrides nothing" error at "override".

Comment: @sleepy idk how to solve it now. Sorry, I tried the best I could